# Is there any implementation of attribute-based encryption on top of Bitcoin?

Tags: encryption

I've found a few papers detailing how you could do it in theory, but haven't seen anything in practice.  Like a system for distributing bitcoin to private keys, where those keys are only distributed if the recipient possesses certain attributes that would unlock the access policy in the transaction.

EDIT: I'm thinking of something like this: ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7846935 where there is a protocol using ABE built on top of, or aside from the Bitcoin protocol, in order to distribute coins based on certain attributes. The keys themselves are distributed by the authority who determines who possesses the attributes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. This sounds interesting, but I don't really understand what you're trying to do. I'm confused with the second sentence. What is being distributed, the keys or the bitcoins? And how would the recipient access the key if they didn't know it in beforehand? Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks for your response and welcome.  I'm thinking of something like this: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7846935/  where there is a protocol using ABE built on top of, or aside from the Bitcoin protocol, in order to distribute coins based on certain attributes.  The keys themselves are distributed by the authority who determines who possesses the attributes.

Comment: I see, that sounds pretty interesting. Please edit your question post to clarify it and flag for reopening. :)

Comment: Thanks, I added the edit.  I agree, it is interesting!  The authors are impossible to locate.